# How to access a factory data object inside of a $routeProvider config in Angular.JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create an Angular.JS calculator, that will return the user back to the root page if a certain factory Data object is empty. My issue is that I cannot figure out how to access the `Data.Terms` object to see if it is empty inside of the `$routeProvider` configuration under the `/condition` path.

In my code below, the section that says `if (!Data.Terms)` is not working. I want it to return the value of Terms stored in the factory Data function:

```
// Creating the module
var myApp = angular.module("app-calculator", ["calculatorControls", "ngRoute"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "termsController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "/content/templates/termsView.html"
        });

        $routeProvider.when("/condition", {
            controller: "conditionController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "/content/templates/conditionView.html",
            resolve: {
                mess: function ($location) {

                    // Check if the Data.Terms field has been completed,
                    // if not then return to the root path.
                    if (!Data.Terms) {
                        $location.path('/');
                    }
                    //

                }
            }
        });

// my Data
myApp.factory('Data', function () {
    var Terms = '';

    return {
        Terms: Terms,
    }
})
```

Comment: try `mess: function($location, Data){`

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you Claies! Post it in an answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should inject `Data` as dependency in your resolve section.

```
var myApp = angular.module("app-calculator", ["calculatorControls", "ngRoute"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "termsController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "/content/templates/termsView.html"
        });

        $routeProvider.when("/condition", {
            controller: "conditionController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "/content/templates/conditionView.html",
            resolve: {
                mess: function ($location, Data) {

                    // Check if the Data.Terms field has been completed,
                    // if not then return to the root path.
                    if (!Data.Terms) {
                        $location.path('/');
                    }
                    //

                }
            }
        });
```